# JQuery bind on Ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bind

Why do we call bind on **AJAX** `success` calls?

Take a look at this code:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: myurl,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        this.setState({data: data});
    }.bind(this)
});
```

If we don't call `bind`, then does it makes any difference or there is an advantage to use `bind` here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to call `bind()` in order to force your callbacks context (`this`) to be the right thing. Otherwise, it is called in the global context by default (apparently, jQuery calls it with a context of the jqXHR object). `bind()` sets the context of your function to whatever `this` is supposed to be.

Comment: Sorry i didnt get this.Would you please elaborate

Comment: If you don't call bind, `this` inside the callback will be the wrong thing.

Comment: I agree with Scimonster.bind() sets the context of your function to whatever this is supposed to be,or your function will give an error like this:Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Answer (score 1):

@shubham, it's the **JavaScript** syntax to use current this in your callback function as you mentioned in:

```
success: function(data){
    this.setState({data: data});
}
```

First argument of `bind()` function will act as this in calling function, you should go through `apply()` and `call()` functions as this would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your code from **React**. Because recently I encounter similar issue dealing with **React**.

Back to your question. I think the `bind` is play a transform function. Code as follow:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
var _this = this;
$.ajax({
  url: this.props.url,
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    _this.setState({data: data});
  }
 });
},
```

is equal to:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
$.ajax({
  url: this.props.url,
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    this.setState({data: data});
  }.bind(this)
 });
},
```

As so for, I think you can understand what is the **bind** function and why using `bind` to achieve it.